# how appoint a specific windows sdk version for cmake build?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, sdk, cmake, visual-studio-2017

I have vs 2017 and   I can set Platform Toolset in IDE:

- Visual Studio 2017 - Windows XP (v141_xp)
- Visual Studio 2017 (v141)
- Visual Studio 2015 (v140)
- Visual Studio 2015 - Windows XP (v140_xp)

I want to cmake build many library(opencv,zlib...) ,and want to build two version:

- one for xp(Visual Studio 2017 - Windows XP (v141_xp)),
- one for windows 10(Visual Studio 2017 (v141))

of course I can cmake output *.sln and open sln ,set up Platform Toolset,build.... but I want to use cmake --build . automatic build

How can I appoint platform toolset  for cmake?

Comment: It is and it isn't a duplicate question. He asks both how to specify the SDK version (which isn't the compiler toolset) and he asks how to specify the toolset. Huh.

Comment: so, he agreed to close it. But there still isn't an answer of how to specify the SDK version... Which, again, isn't the compiler toolset.

Comment: For anyone finding this, the solution is to use CMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION.
eg. cmake -DCMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION=8.1 .